# With accuracy of or with an accuracy of?

Tags: grammar

I am trying to write a paper for publishing. In writing one sentence, I am doubtful which way of writing would be correct.

A Differential Pressure (DP) transmitter with a maximum working pressure of 2000 psi ***and accuracy of*** ± 0.02% reading was used to measure the pressure drop across the core.

A Differential Pressure (DP) transmitter with a maximum working pressure of 2000 psi ***and an accuracy of*** ± 0.02% reading was used to measure the pressure drop across the core.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would use "**an** accuracy of" in this case for parallel structure. This is because you previously wrote "with **a** maximum working pressure of".

Comment: Be sure that you mean accuracy and not precision. If in doubt, look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision

Comment: Many thanks, General Poxter; however, could you please let me know why did you choose an? I ask since I checked both sentences with Grammarly, and it says both are correct! I was wondering whether it was a bug in Grammarly, or they are both correct.

Comment: Grammatically speaking, there's nothing technically "wrong" about either option, since parallel structure sort of hugs the fine line between grammatically correct and stylistically preferable. Regardless, you should always try to have parallel structure in your sentences if applicable since it improves the logic, flow, and readability of your writing.

Comment: Alright, I got the point; thanks again.